# SVG element in list, when I hide the first parent, all of next SVG in each section will be hidden too, but not the container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, next.js

I face a strange bug with `Next`.
With `getServerSideProps`, I made a request to my api folder, this result a simple `JSON`.
All is good.

I display the content perfectly, no problem.

I put on the parent element a `onClick` attribute, who call a function of my `main` file
No problem, all is good too.

But, in this function, I ask to hide the children of the global element.
It works, but, when it's the first occurence of the list, all others `SVG` in the list get hidden too, but in fact, in `CSS`, nothing appears.

Do you know why ?

I post with this a Vercel link, `GitHub` repo, and screens.

I solved this, by changing the `SVG` element, with a `<Image/>` element... But it's not clean...

Vercel Link : [Vercel](https://svg-bug.vercel.app/)

GitHub Repo : [GitHub](https://github.com/MKlersy2/svg-bug)

Screen 1
[image: Initial]

Screen 2
[image: Click on first element]

Screen 3
[image: Click on second element]

Comment: How many elements with id="linearGradient-1ihdxrbknb-1" are you creating. If > 1 then you need to fix that.

Comment: Just one by svg element !

Comment: Are you sure? Each icon creates one and you have a map of them so if your map has more than one entry...

Comment: yeah of course, if map has more than one entry, svg will be displayed each times, but, why this doesn't work with the first entry, but works fine with others ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix, but isn't clean for me... Replace svg component by ... And it's work.
Maybe a bug with id on SVG elements.

Comment: Holy f#@k, how bad this answer is.
Replace SVG with three dots, oh my.